# Trouble pairing Apple TV with Xcode

Tags: xcode, tvos, apple-tv

When trying to pair Xcode with my Apple TV it says

> This device has been ignored in the devices panel.

I cannot continue development properly until this issue has been solved, however I cannot find an un-ignore button. Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Running the terminal command as described in other answers didn't work for me and the device kept being ignored whenever I re-opened Xcode.

My solution was to open [Apple Configurator](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/apple-configurator) and go to Paired Devices on the About menu. From the window that appears hit the X to remove all the devices (I had the same device listed 6 times).

Then close Apple Configurator, launch Xcode and the Apple TV paired.

My setup was Xcode 13.4.1 / Apple 4K 2nd Gen / tvOS 15.5.1 / Apple Configuration 2.15.1

Comment: Thank you !!! This worked for me as well for tvOS 13.4.5 with xCode 12.4 on Catalina

Comment: Thank you this worked for me too on tvOS 16.2 and Xcode 14.2. I never would have guessed this.

Comment: Followed all the steps here but didn't work for me :(. I have Xcode 14.2, macOS 12.6, tvOS 16.2

Answer (score 7):

## Solution 2023

While **Window > Devices and Simulators** is open on the Xcode, go to the upper menu with the back button on your remote and re-enter the **Remote App and Devices** menu to try to go back again. Try a few times. It'll show your device on the Xcode's Device window.

Then click the **Pair** for the device. You’ll see a screen asking you to enter the **six-digit code displayed on your Apple TV**;

Enter the code to the Xcode's Device window. And wait for it. For a while device and Xcode will work for Preparing debugger support for your device. **Keep your Mac device and Apple TV close until it's done.**

**If still having the same issue**, just try restarting your internet. For some reason, some people solved this way‍♂️

Hope this will help someone.

Best.

Comment: Thank you, going in the Remote App and Devices menu solved my issue

Comment: Glad to hear that:)

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the solution. I did a number of things so here are all of them, but the most important one is step 5:

1. Go to main menu in Apple TV
2. Quit Xcode
3. Go to the command line and type

   `defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist DVTIgnoredDevices`
4. You *should* be able to see the AppleTV in question listed there.
5. NOTE: This will clear all of your ignored devices
   . Still in the command line, type

   `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist DVTIgnoredDevices`
6. Go to the Devices and Simulators window
7. On command line, type

   `defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist DVTIgnoredDevices`

You should see something like "does not exist"

8. You should be able to pair the AppleTV now

Comment: This answer is the only thing that worked for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

**2022**

After testing some solutions and having no luck, try the next:

- Restart the router

It's working now.
Try it.

Comment: Lol, after everything else, this is the only thing that has worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using Sonoma (beta) and tvOS 17 beta 3, my MacBook Pro would pair with the TV, but not connect to it (stuck saying "connecting ..."). Both the TV and MacBook were hardwired to the same Ubiquity switch. When I changed both to use the same WiFi network, the connection worked - when I changed back, it got stuck again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, same issue and same solution! I'm going to file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue:
My solution was:

1. Remove everything from the ATV
2. perform the delete command from above
3. Reboot everything!
4. Try the pairing again

This did it for me.
For some reason,  don't ask me why

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've enabled the "Show as run destination" option.[image]

Comment: I am not able to view this screen unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

i tried all the solutions mentioned here - non helped, eventually i:

- selected "Forget Device" from the apple tv
- restarted the apple tv
- closed the XCode
- restarted mac
- paired again and that worked

sometimes when you press |Pair| button in the Devices & Simulators window, after you key in the numbers, the screen will go back to "Pair" mode,

in order to bypass this issue, after pairing i restart the xcode (without unpairing or forget the device), and the device shows up as connected

Comment: Tried this, didn't work :(

Comment: make sure your apple tv and xcode on the same network

Comment: also make sure your apple tv & xcode are both on the same wifi or both connected through cables (if one is on wifi and the other on cable it usually not working, or if one is on 2.4Ghz network and the other is on 5Ghz it will not work [even if they both have the same network mask])

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and none of the solutions above worked. Then I noticed that universal clipboard between my iPhone and Mac was also not working.

The solution for that was to toggle Bluetooth and Wi-Fi on/off on both Mac and iPhone (I have a feeling that it was more the toggle on Mac that helped).

Anyway, by fixing that issue, my AppleTV showed up paired and ready to use in Xcode (din't even have to re-pair).

Answer (score 0):

**June 2023**

All the answers in this post proved how shaky and unreliable a wireless pairing is.

When I connected my Mac laptop and AppleTV to the same network using an ethernet cable, it works. Very consistent and reliable.

[Pair Your Mac To Your AppleTV](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208088)

Environment - MacBook Pro (2015, Intel) with a macOS 12.6, AppleTV 4K (2nd gen) with a tvOS 16.1